# backlink search sources

Tags: seo

Which methods i can use to find backlinks on my site?
for example i can search in google "http://stackoverflow.com" -site:http://stackoverflow.com
all resulted pages can contain backlinks, i must parse all them to check it.
What other good methods exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you will parse them with yourself manually or through software.

Anyway, if you simply want to check back links by yourself, the method that I trust is through Google web master. On that page you can see all the back links that Google considers valid. More information go to www.google.com/webmasters. I am sure you will find lot of more useful info there.

In addition to that, there are lot of third party tools out there, most of them are free by the way. You can find them out by querying phrases like back link checker via Google and give a shot. Personally I do not trust them, because the links they provide are very different from each others as well as from Google. In such situation I usually tend to Google.

Good luck.

Comment: in google webmaster i can check them only for my sites (i must confirm this then add) I search for methods to check any site. I am not intrested in tools i interested in methods what they use.